Integer hashing with basic arithmetic
I am currently working in a language made for the Hypixel Housing gamemode in Minecraft called HSL, which only supports basic arithmetic, namely subtraction, multiplication and division. All numbers are also 64 bit integers, with no strings or fancy operations beside the ones mentioned above.
I've been looking for a while and have yet to find any proper basic hashing methods within these guidelines.
I have attempted to get assistance on this through various means such as this gist but have trouble implementing it within the rules I outlined above.

Are they signed or unsigned 64 bit integers input? What output do you want? 32bit? Can't you add?

Sorry for not clarifying, we're working with 64 bit signed integers at the minute, so -2^63 up to 2^63. Output same thing.

It's not entirely clear what your constraints are, but if you want a strong hash function using those basic operations, one easy (but somewhat slow) way is to slice the 64-bit number into say either 8-bit indices into tables of 256 random 64-bit numbers.  For positive numbers, you can effectively shift right by dividing by a power of two, and shift left by multiplying by a power of two: using this with subtraction, you can find out the 0..255 value of any given 8-bit slice of the input, then use it as an array input.  With a bit more thought or special casing, you can get it working for negative numbers.  Get the eight numbers from the table and XOR them together.
